# Is python requests missing something that is present in curl?

Tags: python, php, python-requests, php-curl

So i have had this api i am trying to automate using python. I already did it in php curl and it works just fine. The api doesn't have a certificate and so instead i used `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false` in php and this just works fine. However Python requests also sees this certificate issue and so i used `verify=False` when doing a post request. The problem comes in when i send a post request to the login url using python. The server returns a 404 response saying the requested url doesn't exist on the server. Here is my php code

```
<?php

function post($url,$post,$header){
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_PORT => 3456,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    ));
    return json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
}

function login($m, $p){
    $ua = array("Connection:keep-alive","User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; M2006C3LG Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/87.0.4280.101 Mobile Safari/537.36","Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8","Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate");
    $data = "email=".$m."&password=".$p."";
    $login = post("https://aartre.com/user/login",$data,$ua);
    print_r($login);
}

$mail = "email@gmail.com";
$pass = "password";
login($mail, $pass);

?>
```

This php code returns a token allocated during login which means it's working.

Here is my python code

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

s = requests.Session()


requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

headers = {
    "Host":"aartre.com:3456",
    "Connection":"keep-alive",
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; M2006C3LG Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/87.0.4280.101 Mobile Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate"
}

def get(url):
    return s.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)

def post(url, data):
    return s.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, verify=False)

def login(email, password):
    url = "https://aartre.com/user/login"
    data = "email={email}&password={password}"
    res = post(url, data)
    print(res.text)

email = "email@gmail.com"
password = 'password'

login(email, password)
```

This code doesn't have any  error as i see it. The login url is also correct and the same as the one used in php. But after running it. this is the response

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/7.3.30 Server at aartre.com Port 3456</address>
</body></html>
```

What might be the problem? Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your ```data``` is correct? The way you have it there makes it look like the email and password are a part of the URL params which is definitely not how login are defined. Can you try with this: `data={'email': email, 'password': password}`

Also, this might not be the issue though. It looks like the URL isn't available for some reason.

Comment: The url is available and the post request takes in form data not json

Comment: Also the problem is in the login url. Is the url only not available for python alone? because if you try the php code above it works fine. But using python then it says not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified to CURL `CURLOPT_PORT => 3456`. According to the docs:

> This option sets number to be the remote port number to connect to, instead of the one specified in the URL or the default port for the used protocol.

So CURL has no magic capability really. The equivalent Python `requests` would be explicitly specifying the port in the URL. And as @whiplash pointed out, the POST data should be a `dict`:

```py
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

s = requests.Session()


requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

headers = {
    "Host":"aartre.com:3456",
    "Connection":"keep-alive",
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; M2006C3LG Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/87.0.4280.101 Mobile Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate"
}

def get(url):
    return s.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)

def post(url, data):
    return s.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, verify=False)

def login(email, password):
    url = "https://aartre.com:3456/user/login"
    data = {'email': email, 'password': password}
    res = post(url, data=data)
    print(res.text)

email = "email@gmail.com"
password = 'password'

login(email, password)
```

Note that the response coming back I believe is a JSON string, so you might consider printing `res.json()` rather than `res.text`.

**Update**

Since you are using a `Session` instance, it is more usual to set any headers that you want to use for each request in the `Session` instance itself and in that way you do not need to explicitly specify headers on each request:

```py
import requests

from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)


def login(email, password):
    url = "https://aartre.com:3456/user/login"
    data = {'email': email, 'password': password}
    res = s.post(url, data=data, verify=False)
    result = res.json()
    print(result)


with requests.Session() as s:
    headers = {
        "Connection":"keep-alive",
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; M2006C3LG Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/87.0.4280.101 Mobile Safari/537.36",
        "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate"
    }

    s.headers.update(headers)

    email = "email@gmail.com"
    password = 'password'

    login(email, password)
```